# persistence xml on openshift and enviromental variables

Tags: mysql, openshift, persistence.xml

I'm trying to deploy a simple application to Openshift, but I'm confused about its enviromental variables. They are used to access the mysql database that is installed. I saw a few examples but perhaps someone could tell me if I'm doing something wrong.

My persistence.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />                
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/app" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Does the persistence.xml get parsed to use the openshift env variables or do I need to do something else? I'm currently getting this stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Must specify port after ':' in connection string
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.parseHostPortPair(NonRegisteringDriver.java:190)
    com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.parseURL(NonRegisteringDriver.java:672)
    com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:296)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
    org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:70)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:377)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:336)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:91)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.findOne(Unknown Source)
    com.melladopro.jms.PersonController.listQuestions(PersonController.java:38)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

And it's weird because I can see the port just fine when i do `env | grep OPENSHIFT`.

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the pre-configured MySQLDS data source in your persistence.xml file, use this example but change KitchensinkQuickstartDS to MySQLDS: https://github.com/openshift/kitchensink-example/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

The pre-configured DS is in the standalone.xml file. You can also reference this quick start for more information about the pre-configured data sources: https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1086-how-to-use-the-pre-configured-mysqlds-and-postgresqlds-data-sources-in-the-java

Comment: Worked for me, thank you!  I had to put the env vars in the standalone-openshift.xml